# Can I write any element from a cyclic group as a power of other any element from that cyclic group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I've got G, a **cyclic** group, and x and y two element from G. Let's suppose that **o(x)|o(y)**. Can we make sure that x is a power of y? (I mean, can we make sure that we can write **x=y^(something)** ?) I need to **prove** this, it's not enough with an example.

---

I know that as G is a cyclic group, it is generated by only one element: G = < g > and the elements from G are the powers of g:
 G = < g > = {1, g, g^2, g^3, . . . ,g^n} being |G|=n < infinite.
So if I call g=y, so that we have G = < y > = {1, y, y^2, y^3, . . . ,y^n}, I can say that if any of those elements is x, I can write x as a power of y.

But if y is for exaple y=g^2 or y=g^3... can I always write x as a power of y? Taking into account that o(x)|o(y)

Comment: Could you please use latex to write math?

Comment: Here is a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be a cyclic group and $y,x\in G$ be elements of the group such that $o(x)|o(y)$. First thing to observe is that $H=\langle y \rangle \subset G$ and $K=\langle x \rangle \subset G$, and that both $H$ and $K$ are the unique subgroups of $G$ with orders $o(y)$ and $o(x)$ respectively. Since $H$ is a cyclic group itself, and $o(x)|o(y)$ there's a subgroup $L$ of $H$ with order $o(x)$, which is also a cyclic subgroup of $G$ of order $o(x)$. This tells us that $L=K$, and so $x\in \langle y \rangle$ which in turn implies that $y^k=x$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: But for that o(x) and o(y) have to divide |G|, right? Or do they divide |G| always?

Comment: This is a fact for every finite group $G$. If $a\in G$, then $o(a)|o(G)$. It is called Lagrange's theorem. Try proving this yourself. It's not too bad. Hint: use conjugation as a automorphism.

Comment: Also use Latex to write math, it is not pleasing to look at your question.

Comment: And one last question, you've written that H and K are part of G and then you say that they are subgroups of G. (I know that if they are subgroups they also are part of G but) where you've witten that they are part of G, I can write the symbol of subgroup, right?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to use Latex; I would try for the following question :(